# sort a PivotTable in excel vba from 2 input field

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table, vba

I'm trying to figure out how I can sort a pivot table by using 2 input field from the end user. At the moment I can only do it with one. The code I have right now is:

```
Private Sub SortingBox_Change()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim CB As ComboBox

Set PT = Worksheets("Tableau Dynamique").PivotTables("LEO")
Set CB = SortingBox

If CB.Text = "Asc - % relevé en ligne" Then
    PT.PivotFields("No Marchand").AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="% relevé en ligne"

ElseIf CB.Text = "Desc - % relevé en ligne" Then
    PT.PivotFields("No Marchand").AutoSort Order:=xlDescending, Field:="% relevé en ligne"

ElseIf CB.Text = "No Marchand" Then
    PT.PivotFields("No Marchand").AutoSort Order:=xlAscending, Field:="No Marchand"

End If
End Sub
```

It works OK, but I need a list entry for every Ascending and Descending Scenario. I would prefer to set AutoSort.Order with a separate ComboBox from the one setting the Field. The only problem is that when I try to do that, it tells me that I don't have enough Arguments.

Does anyone know what I could do to sort that out?

Comment: Can you clarify your question further? Perhaps you could link to an image showing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry if it wasn't clear. In the mean time. I found a solution during the weekend. For Anyone, if they are looking for something similar here what I did.

First to clarify:

I have a dynamic table and I want the end user to have a convivial way to sort the table (Without VBA they would have to go in the main column open the sorting menu and choose the additional sorting option, than select a bunch of option to get what they want and its not very clear what you have to do if you don't really know how).

I chose to put ComboBox so it can be easier to do the sorting like that:
[ComboBoxImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMVQy.png). Sorry its french. In short, they would have a ComboBox to do the sorting based on (1) the Field, (2) the Order, (3) the pivotline (based on the month they want)

To simplify the code I instead created a variable for each ComboBox that would be able to interact with the AutoSort Method. The final code look like this:

```
Public Sub Sorter()
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim OrderValue As String
Dim OrderSort As XlSortOrder
Dim FieldValue As String
Dim MonthValue As Integer
Dim TableName As String

On Error Resume Next

TableName = "LEO"
Set PT = Worksheets("Tableau Dynamique").PivotTables(TableName)
OrderValue = Range("OrderingBoxValue").Value
FieldValue = Range("SortingBoxValue").Value
MonthValue = Range("MonthInt").Value

If OrderValue = "Ascendant" Then
    OrderSort = xlAscending
ElseIf OrderValue = "Descendant" Then
    OrderSort = xlDescending
End If

If MonthValue = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).PivotFields("No Marchand").AutoSort OrderSort _
    , FieldValue
Else
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).PivotFields("No Marchand").AutoSort OrderSort _
    , FieldValue, ActiveSheet.PivotTables(TableName).PivotColumnAxis. _
    PivotLines(MonthValue), 1
End If
End Sub
```

Basically, I linked the ComboBox to cells in another sheet and I invoke the Sub on ComboBox_Change.

Obviously, if anyone think they have a more efficient or overall better solution I would be glad to see it. I'm fairly new to VBA so I'm sure my code could be improved.